# Check if tokens have been substituted

Tags: java, token, velocity

I use Apache Velocity to substitute tokens in a templates which looks like this:

```xml
<batch>
    #set( $appName = "helloworld" )
    #set( $appDisplayName = "Hello World App")
    #set( $appVersion = "1.0")
    <registerapplication>
        <appkey>$appkey</appkey>
        <appname>$appName</appname>
        <appversion>$appVersion</appversion>
        <appdescriptiondefault>$appDisplayName</appdescriptiondefault>
    </registerapplication>
</batch>
```

The following three lines of code do the trick:

```java
Velocity.init();
StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
Velocity.evaluate(new VelocityContext(), w, "", new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
```

It works perfect, but I have an additional requirement. If some substitutions has really been made, the user should get a notification. Otherwise, i.e. if a template looks like

```xml
<batch>
    #set( $appName = "helloworld" )
    #set( $appDisplayName = "Hello World App")
    #set( $appVersion = "1.0")
    <registerapplication>
        <appkey>$appkey</appkey>
        <appname>helloworld</appname>
        <appdescriptiondefault>Hello World App</appdescriptiondefault>
    </registerapplication>
</batch>
```

no actions should be taken.

Any idea how to achieve that?

**upd** Thanks to Claude Brisson. My solution looks as follows:

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
EventCartridge eventCartridge = new EventCartridge();
velocityContext.attachEventCartridge(eventCartridge);
eventCartridge.addReferenceInsertionEventHandler(new ReferenceInsertionEventHandler()
{
      @Override
    public Object referenceInsert(String reference, Object value)
    {
        if (!varSubsituted && value != null)
        {
            varSubsituted = true;
        }
        return value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reference insertion handler.

First, create your handler class:

```
package mypackage;
import org.apache.velocity.app.event.ReferenceInsertionEventHandler;

public class MyHandler implements ReferenceInsertionEventHandler
{
    public Object referenceInsert( String reference, Object value  )
    {
        // ...notify user...
    }
}
```

You can then register your handler in your *velocity.properties* file, with:

```
eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class = mypackage.UserNotifyHandler
```

In a multi-threaded application, since Velocity is single-threaded, you can use a global thread specific variable to hold involved the user's info, since you'll need it from within your handler.